# Recursion - Concentric Circles

Tags: graphics, functions, function-construction, programming, recursion

I'm trying to develop my Wolfram programming skills and set myself an exercise of creating concentric circles using a recursive delayed function:

```
drawCircle[x_, y_, r_] :=
     Graphics[Circle[{x, y}, r]];
     If[r > 10, drawCircle[x, y, r/2], Break];
```

Since I'm not using a `Do`, `While` or `For` loop, my use of Break is probably wrong too, but my logic is to exit recursion when r is less than 10.

This code creates a series of overlay objects rather than concentric circles:

[image]

I have tried joining the output objects but without much success.

Desired output (using delayed function recursion):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, since Mathematica does not care about nesting lists for graphics primitives, the most simple solution is this:

```
drawCircle[x_, y_, r_ /; r > 10] := {Circle[{x, y}, r], drawCircle[x, y, r/2]};
drawCircle[__] := {}
drawCircle[0, 0, 200] // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you will say, wait, that is not what I wanted and you are correct. Dividing radii is not the correct operation. You need to subtract in the recursion:

```
drawCircle[x, y, r - 50]
```

and then you get

```
drawCircle[0, 0, 250] // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I had not thought about using the condition as a function argument - nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[drawCircle];
drawCircle[a_: 0, b_: 1/2][{x_, y_}, r_] := Circle[{x, y}, r] /. 
  c_Circle :> If[r > 10, {c, drawCircle[a, b][{x, y}, a + b r]}, c]

Graphics[drawCircle[][{0, 0}, 200]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[drawCircle[-50, 1][{0, 0}, 250]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[drawCircle];
drawCircle[{x_, y_}, r_] := 
 If[r > 10, drawCircle[{x, y}, r/2], Circle[{x, y}, r]]

Cases[Trace[drawCircle[{0, 0}, 200]], _Circle, -1] // Union // Graphics
```